# I want to have more than one footnote in a table. What's the best way to get this to work right?

Tags: tables, footnotes

I want to have more than one footnote in a table.  But then the footnote counter has incremented too many times by the time I've gotten to the first `\footnotetext`.  What is the best way to get this to work right?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ \vfill\

\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
\hline
First & footnote.\footnotemark  \\ 
Second & footnote.\footnotemark   \\ 
Third & footnote.\footnotemark  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\footnotetext{First}  \footnotetext{Second} \footnotetext{Third}

Fourth footnote.\footnote{Four}

\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please undelete your `roman` counter question and clearify it a little bit, it can be answered, I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\footnotemark` does increase the value of the `footnote` counter, but this will get out of sync when `\footnotetext` is used.

One has to reset the `footnote` counter *after* the `tabular` environment to the state *before*. This can be done either manually, but might become tedious, if the values change or it's done with a dummy counter, which holds the `footnote` counter before `tabular` and is then restored to the original number after `tabular` (Done here with `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AfterEndEnvironment` commands from `etoolbox` package.

However, `\footnotetext` does not increment the `footnote`. Either use a `pretocmd` -- approach or use a wrapper macro `\myfootnotetext` which does this stepping automatically. (Or do it manually.)

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\myfootnotetext}[1]{%
\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{#1}%
}

\newcounter{dummycounter}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{%
  \setcounter{dummycounter}{\value{footnote}}%
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{%
  \setcounter{footnote}{\value{dummycounter}}%
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
\hline
First & footnote.\footnotemark  \\ 
Second & footnote.\footnotemark   \\ 
Third & footnote.\footnotemark  \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\myfootnotetext{First}
  \myfootnotetext{Second} \myfootnotetext{Third}

Fourth footnote.\footnote{Four}

%\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to consider using a `table` environment, the `tablefootnote` package solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[colorlinks]{article}%

\usepackage{footnotebackref}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}

\begin{document}
\mbox{}\vfill
A first footnote\footnote{First}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
  \begin{tabular}{|r|l|}
    \hline
    First & footnote.\tablefootnote{Second} \\
    Second & footnote.\tablefootnote{Third} \\
    Third & footnote.\tablefootnote{Fourth} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

Fifth footnote.\footnote{Fifth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspected there would be package ;-) (+1)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: You suspect good. It's not very old (end of 2011).

Comment: I was too lazy too look after, so I did the hard way ;-), however, you should change `footnotetable` in `tablefootnote` then ;-)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the typo, Christian! I'm afraid you'll have a big job with me…

Comment: Why? Did you wrote `footnotetable` in a lot of other answers? :-P

Comment: I'm sure I'll write `foottablenote` or `foottablenote` some days. Maybe a table consisting only in footnotes. That'd be nice!